# How to keep all Autopopulate list values always visible using AngularJS

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angularjs, html

How to show autopopulate list values always visible even enter non-relevant text in Textbox.

Example: 
if I enter 'Ora' in textbox, I'm getting only 'Orange'

[image]

**I want to show all values in the list value**

[image]

[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/3etbtfwL/295/)

Please suggest any way to achieve this case.

```
<div data-ng-app='httpApp' data-ng-controller='httpAppCtrlr'>       
        <input list="values" placeholder="select">
<datalist id="values">
 <option ng-repeat="item in items" value="{{item}}" ></option>
</datalist>

</div>
```

Comment: Have you solved this issue, looks like the jsfiddle does exactly what you want.

Comment: @ErsinDemirtas No. If I enter 'ora', I'm getting only 'Orange' in my autodropdown list but I want to see all the list values. I updated the questions respectively.

Comment: Do you want to have macthed value at top of list and other below? 
Or whole list without changing order?